# Difference in setting "proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;" outside and inside nginx location {} block

Tags: node.js, express, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am trying to pass a secure cookie to node express JS app and using Nginx as web frontend. For successful implementation, nginx should pass 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header with value 'https'. The implementation of secure cookie will fail if I specify 'proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $scheme;' outside the nginx location {} block have proxy_pass statement.

I want to know the difference between specifying proxy_set_header inside nginx location {} block and outside it.

Secure Cookie will fail in this case:

```
server {
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  location {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
  }
}
```

Secure cookie will pass in this case:

```
server {
  location {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried printing the "req" through "console.log" and found that it did not pick the value of "X-Forwarded-Proto" when mentioned outside location {} block.

Comment: When you configure proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme outside the location block, do you have any other proxy_set_header configurations in the location block? If yes, the proxy_set_header from outer level will not be inherited.